# JSON Schema Output Object rather than Array

Tags: json

I've set up a custom post and added various custom fields using Advanced Custom Fields. The data can be viewed here: khclassics-co-uk.stackstaging.com/wp-json/wp/v2/classic_car

However, when I validate the schema, I get an error: Invalid type. Expected Object but got Array.

To validate I'm using the schema from here: carandclassic.co.uk/feed/schema.json

How I can output an Object rather than an Array? I've looked in various place but can't find an answer that works.

Comment: What do you mean you're validating your scheme with carandclassic.co.uk/feed/schema.json? That schema is for a different website, and the data is formatted completely differently with entirely different fields. Of course they're not going to match.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around, I followed the advice that setting up a custom post with custom fields would generate the correct schema data.

Comment: Correct scheme data for what? What does carandclassic’s schema have to do with it? I’m very unclear on what exactly you’re attempting to do.

Comment: I'm trying to add schema data to each car so that the car and classic site can scan for new adverts and add to their own listing. I've been given a custom schema and an example of the JSON data. I need to match their schema so that the advert matches their requirements for listing.

Comment: Well you're a very long way off. There's no simple fix. Your API endpoint needs to return data in the format that schema.json describes, but the default WordPress post type endpoint does not return data in a similar format, so you'll likely need to develop your own endpoint from scratch that returns data in a matching format. To start with you're going to need to learn how to read the schema file to begin with, because you'll need to be able to match it. You can learn what JSON schema is and how it works here: https://json-schema.org.